# Dell Vostro 14-5459 Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi slow when plugged in

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, wireless-access-point, dell-vostro

I bought my Dell Vostro 14-5459 with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. From the start, Wi-Fi speed is almost non-existent when the laptop is connected to the charger. As soon as I unplug it, the speed increases and web pages load very fast.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 (in-place upgrade, not a clean install) but the problem persists.

Strangely, the issue only occurs on my home Wi-Fi network and NOT when connected to my mobile hotspot. I have not tested this in a different environment but intend to that if I can't find a solution here. No issues with the home Wi-Fi as our other laptop (running Ubuntu 16.04), 2x smartphones, and tablet all connect with no issues.

Below output for `lspci`:

```
collen@collen:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
```

Most recently I have tried turning off power management, but that did not work.

Anyone have any ideas or advice?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Happy to provide extra info if needed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that turning off power management “did not work”? Did you not manage to turn off power management or did it not result in a more speedy wireless network? How exactly did you try to turn it off and confirm that the changes were in effect?

Comment: Hi David, I used `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` and tried to connect while on AC power. I assume this actually turned off power management as the output of `sudo iwconfig` after a reboot showed power management set back to on. Actions based on this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1678098, which is the exact opposite problem that I am having, but all I could find. Any advice? Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Yes, `iwconfig [INTERFACE] power off` turns of power management and it's not persistent across system restarts but that can be achieved through other means. But before we look into that, did it improve the situation before the next reboot?

Comment: No, it did not.

Comment: What are the option values of the wireless driver kernel module? You can find them in `/sys/module/{iwlwifi,*80211*}/parameters/`. I can see there are two for power management and one to disable 802.11 Annex N (which seems to help many people).

Comment: @DavidFoerster OK, I have no idea if I'm looking at the right thing, but inside the parameters folder I have two files that are obviously power related. 1) "power_level" with a value of "0", and  2) "power_save" with a value of "N". Then there is "antenna_coupling" value "0", "11n_disable" value "0". Does this help at all? Again, thanks for taking the time, David.

Comment: Yes, that helps. It shows that power saving is already disabled in the module. The only thing that I can think of to try is to set `11n_disable` to 1 (see [here for instructions](/a/213792/175814)).

Comment: @DavidFoerster OK, I implemented the top answer from that question and created a file: `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-disable11n.conf` and set it to: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 power_save=0` which appears to have worked. Or, this could just be one of the rare times when a reboot does the trick. I will see how it acts going forward. For now, I have also found a workaround. Using  ASUS USB N14 Wireless N300 USB Adapter (https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN14/) -- which I have in my bag for when I travel and end up too far away from the router -- my Wi-Fi speed is fast when my laptop is plugged in.

Comment: If the linked question turns out to resolve the issue for you, please bring it to my attention so I can flag yours as a duplicate. Or do it yourself if you happen to earn 15 reputation until then to receive the [privilege to flag posts](/help/privileges/flag-posts).